# record audio on blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I followed this guide:[How To - Record Audio on a BlackBerry smartphone](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1089414/How_To_-_Record_audio_on_a_BlackBerry_smartphone.html?nodeid=1311883&vernum=0)

but there is en error in line `_player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://audio");`:

> the method createPlayer(String) is undefined For the type Manager

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you accidently import `net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager` instead of `javax.microedition.media.Manager`

Comment: Hey Rihan already gave the answer. I observed from so many days, when question raises The first answer given by Rihan only. Good keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
```

add

```
import javax.microedition.media.Manager;
```